# My laptop microphone is stuttering a lot (Asus ROG, Realtek drivers)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, microphone, audio-recording, realtek-hd-audio

My laptop microphone had no issues at first but for the last couple of months, I noticed that other people cannot hear me properly on Zoom meetings and other platforms. For testing, I recorded my voice and found out that the audio playback was very inconsistent. The playback sound jumps back and forth between a very loud and a barely audible tone. Both my built-in and headset microphones are having the same issue. However, when I connected my headset microphone to my phone, it was working fine. I was quite sure that this had got to do something with my audio drivers. So I took the following approach:

1. Re-installed Realtek Audio Drivers (Did not fix)
2. Disabled audio enhancements (Did not fix)
3. Increased the microphone level and boost (Did not fix)
4. Installed High Definition Audio Drivers instead of Realtek (Still did not fix)

One more thing that I should clear out: This problem seemed to have been occurring since I installed Zoom. Is it possible that Zoom messed up my audio drivers somehow? If not, then what should I do?

Comment: Zoom audio settings allow you to have the mike gain set automatically (i.e., constantly changing, based on volume and background noise), or to *manually set gain*. Have you adjusted that in the Zoom GUI?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes, I disabled the "Automatically adjust the microphone volume" option. Still did not work.